# Evaluating performance of Mule ESB Server and Mule ESB applications in Community Edition

Tags: performance, containers, mule, esb

I am using mule community edition v3.4 and would like to do a complete performance (including overhead) analysis of the mule container itself plus the performance analysis of the individual deployed Mule ESB applications. What are the industry best practices to do this when we are not using the enterprise edition. Which tools are being used today for such purpose?

I also want to analyze the performance overhead of adding the mule container to my existing set of servers which also hosts other containers like tomcat and all.

Thanks in advance,
Jai Shammi Raj Kulkarni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a performance analysis at java level, using a profiler (visualvm, yourkit, etc). That will allow to analyze memory, cpu, etc on a host with different java containers.

For the analysis of the applications deployed to mule, you ca use the jmx beans that mule exposes.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JMX+Management